# Map to store generic type functions in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to create a Map with String and functions as key and Value. It works if all functions are of same signature but my requirement is to store functions of different signature in the same map. Is this possible in Go?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    functions := buildFunctions()
    f := functions["isInValid"]

    //  f("hello")

}

func buildFunctions() map[string]func() bool {

    functions := map[string]func() bool{
        "isInValid":   isInValid,
        "isAvailable": isAvailable,
    }
    return functions
}

func isInValid(s string) bool {
    fmt.Println("Invalid ", s)
    return true
}

func isAvailable(s string, s1 string) bool {
    return true
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ocwCgEpa_0G

Comment: Could you describe the use-case for this, e.g. why can't the different functions be stored in different maps.

Comment: Yes, use `interface{}` as the value type. To call functions use type assertions to specific types or reflection.  Describe the higher-level problem that you are trying to solve.  There may be a better solution to that problem.

Comment: The cleanest way would be to just use two maps, one for each signature.

Comment: I don't understand. Why so many down votes. It's a good question. Scenarios like this are quite useful, especially in case of implementing factory pattern or something similar in go. Desire to be able to do things that are possible in one language, in other(in a decent way), is a genuine step in learning a new language.

Comment: This is not as bad as it is made out to be with all the downvoting from people who think they know it all. A command catalog is made of different function pointers mapped to different strings. In configuration, you will know which function to call depending on the string. This happens all the time in Java with the spring framework. What else is a bean factory? A good solution to this would solve the problem of dependency inversion nicely. Auto wiring by name is possible only because of this kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go is a strongly typed language. So, it's not possible the way, it is possible with, say python. But just like python, once you do this, you loose the benefit of compile time error checks, and your runtime error checking has to be full-proof.
Here's what you can do:

1. **Use `map[string]interface{}` type for your function map**, which enables you to store anything. But then you are responsible to correctly type assertion at the time of calling. Problem is that, in most cases, if while calling a function, you could know the type of function, may be you might not need a map in the first place.
2. **Use a `map[string]string` or `map[string]interface{}` as the argument**, and return type in all the functions that are supposed to go into this map. Or at least put all the variable arguments into this map.

   eg.

   `map[string](func (name string, age int, other_attributes
   map[string]interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error))`

But again, each function call should provide the correct arguments, and there should also be checks inside the functions, to see (with non-panic version of map lookup), if the parameters are correctly provided, if not, you can return a custom error like ErrInvalidParametersPassed. (playing the role of an interpreter). But you will still have lesser chances of messing up, compared to first option. As the `burden of type assertion` will be on the function implementation, and not the caller. Caller just needs to fetch it's required values, which it anyways needs to know about.

But yet, best option would be to redesign your actual solution in a way, so that it can be done without going this road. As @bereal suggested in comments, it's good to have separate maps if possible, or maybe use a superset of arguments if they aren't too different, or too many. If there are just a few arguments, even switch case could be clean enough. Look for ways that cheat/bypass compile time checks, when you are truly convinced that there is no other elegant way.

Comment: SO can I use `map[string]interface{}` for a kind of Key/Value structure where key will always be a `string` but the value could be either string, int or even a list?

Comment: @Volatil3 : Yes, you can do it. The value can even be a map, a struct, or even another map[string]interface (an analogy will be JSON, where every key's value can be as much of a JSON, as its parent is). But I will suggest to use it only if there's not other type-safe way to do things.